# Row of $A = BC$ as a linear combination of the rows of $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove that any row of a matrix $A = BC$ can be written as a linear combination of the rows of $C$. I am able to visualize it with an example, but finding it difficult to prove with notations of vector space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of matrix multiplication, $A_{i,j}=\sum_k B_{i,k}C_{k,j}$.

So a row of $A$ looks like $[\sum_k B_{i,k}C_{k,1},\sum_k B_{i,k}C_{k,2},\dots,\sum_k B_{i,k}C_{k,n}]$.

But that is the same as $$\sum_k[ B_{i,k}C_{k,1}, B_{i,k}C_{k,2},\dots, B_{i,k}C_{k,n}]\\=\sum_k B_{i,k}[ C_{k,1}, C_{k,2},\dots, C_{k,n}]$$

Clearly that row vector is the $k$'th row of $C$, so this last expression is a linear combination of the rows of $C$.